# Using powershell ssh doesn't show terminal colors

Tags: powershell, ssh

I was using windows10 powershell to access to my raspberry pi which is raspbian system. When I use only `ssh user_name@raspberrypi`, I was able to see different colors for directories, executable files, etc.

But **there was 1 time that I tried to use `ssh -Y user_name@raspberrypi`** (because I want to see some pictures by `evince` but it turns out I didn't have X window on my Windows) then there was no color shown for different kind of files.

I tried to not use -Y but the colors didn't came back, also I closed the powershell window and reopen it, `ssh user_name@raspberrypi` still has no color for files.

I checked terminal colors on vnc viewer directly and there **were** colors. Why this happens and how can I see the colors again?

**Update**: I tried to access another PC by ssh, but I **can** see colors for different kinds of files! And I still can't see colors when I access my rasp pi, it's very wired... (again, if I access my pi via vnc viewer I can see colors on terminal directly)

Comment: There are some answers at https://askubuntu.com about colors in your terminal for ssh sessions. See: [how-to-get-coloured-terminal-over-ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16336/how-to-get-coloured-terminal-over-ssh) Note that to me this seems unrelated to having (once) used the `-Y` option as that should have no effect on future sessions ... yes, it is weird, but probably going to remain one of life's mysteries. In general, all the answers over at AU have you checking your .bashrc file (on the remote machine, I presume). In particular pay attention to this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/608096

Answer (score 0):

This is solved to add:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

in my `.bash_profile`

The situation is: At the first time there isn't a `.bash_profile` in my home directory, so when I use ssh the `.bashrc` is loaded every time.

I don't remember well but maybe at some point I created the `.bash_profile` and added something, if I use ssh, this time the `.bash_profile` will be loaded instead of `.bashrc` (the color setting is in `.bashrc` and it was not loaded) so I have no color on terminal.